# Execute a PHP file as a frontend and backend API call

Tags: php, jquery

I have an API helper written in `api_helper.php`. I am doing a frontend API call using AJAX in jQuery. Now I also need to call a specific function `getDataFromAPI()` defined in `api_helper.php` for that I am doing backend API call -

In api_helper.php

```php
    function getDatafromAPI($ gstNo){
        $response = fun($gstNo); // some xyz function for getting API data
        return $response;
    }

    $gstNo= $_GET['gstNo'];
    if(!empty($gstNo)) {
        echo getDatafromAPI($gstNo);
    }
```

Frontend API call (`file.tpl`)

```js
   var gstNo=$('#gstNo').val();
   jQuery.ajax({
           method: "GET",
           dataType: 'json',
           url:"api_helper.php/?gstNo="+gstNo,
           success: function(response){
              // doing something with data
              
           }
```

Backend API call (`fileProcess.php`)-

```php
include('api_helper.php');
$GSTIN = 'xyz';
$response = getDataFromAPI($GSTIN);
```

Frontend API is working fine and returning data when data when doing AJAX call while backend API is not returning response as It is executing whole script of `api_helper.php` (because If I comment the code just below the `getDataFromAPI()`, backend API works fine).
Doubts-

1. How can I restrict execution to only function `getAPIFromData`? or
   any other suggestion?
2. Pls also clarify how can I call a specific php function (from a php
   script) using AJAX jQuery

Answer (score 0):

In your file.tpl you are requesting variable gstin
change in your api_helper.php this line

```
 $gstNo= $_GET['gstNo'];
```

to

```
 $gstNo= $_GET['gstin'];
```

Thanks.

Comment: that's typo while writing Ques.

Comment: This seems you have edited your question.

Comment: Yeah, Am i not allowed to edit ques?